# How can i download android mobile ads sdk like the one there is for amazon?

Tags: android

I have visited this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download . There is option Select the tab for your platform: i keep the default tab selected. There is no link to downloads ads api for android. For amazon it was https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/sdk . Amazon provides abig download button to download ads sdk . Where can  i find one for google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Google Play service API includes the Ads library. You can also download the Ads jar separate

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid

Also check this link.how to set up Google Play Service

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

**Note this :**
Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.

Comment: so i can download it from sdk manager that comes with eclipe and where is this google play version of mobile ads sdk. Is it also downloadable from eclipse sdk manager.

Comment: I visted the link developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html  and have one more question since you said "On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then" so i should use Google play services to integrate ads instead.